# Comparable options/commands from tectia to openssh, like AllowHosts, AllowSHosts etc..?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd

Is there anything comparable options/commands for openssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config like

- AllowHosts
- AllowSHosts

in tectia, without using of hosts.allow, hosts.deny, iptables, etc.. or something like fail2ban

I already use AllowUsers for allow **user@host**

Where i can compare the options of both?